# How would I get the 2nd max date with if

Tags: sql-server

How would I get the 2nd max date if there is date entered as today? Note I always need to select the yesterdays date.

```
Select * 
From MyList
Where Date = (Select Max(Date)
```

Comment: Sample data would greatly help getting the point of your question across to other readers.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Nobody can really help you here because we have no idea what you are trying to do with a vague description. A [mcve] would help considerably.

Comment: I really don't follow what you're asking here. You want the "2nd max date" if it's today, but the date should always be yesterday? How can a date be today *and* yesterday?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion On my list im trying to get the 2nd max date on date column for example

Comment: Name Date
Maria 2/2/2020
John 2/2/2020
JM    2/2/2020
Ryan 2/14/2020
JR     2/15/2020
Jun         2/17/2020

Comment: for example there date on date column next highest date is 2/15/2020 then i want to  select 2/15/2020 as this is the next max before todays date

Comment: You should be updating your question, @ramon , by using the [edit] functionality, not putting sample data (which isn't easily consumed) in the comments. We'll also need to expected results to go with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be:

```
Select * 
From MyList
Where Date = (Select top 1 Date from MyList where Date < (select Max(Date) from MyList) order by Date DESC)
```

Which translates roughly to: Select everything from your list where Date is equal to the date where date is less than the largest date

Based on the on the comments ramon posted I believe this is what he needs:

```
    SELECT TOP 1  [date] FROM (
    SELECT MAX(DATE) [date]
    FROM MyList
    WHERE [DATE] <
    (
        SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM MyList
    )
    AND EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 FROM MyList WHERE [DATE] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    )
    UNION
    SELECT MAX(DATE)
    FROM MyList
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 FROM MyList WHERE [DATE] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    )) x ORDER BY [x].[date] desc
```

Everything together:

```
SELECT * from MyList where [Date] = (
    SELECT TOP 1  [date] FROM (
    SELECT MAX(DATE) [date]
    FROM MyList
    WHERE [DATE] <
    (
        SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM MyList
    )
    AND EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 FROM MyList WHERE [DATE] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    )
    UNION
    SELECT MAX(DATE)
    FROM MyList
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 FROM MyList WHERE [DATE] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    )) x ORDER BY [x].[date] desc)
```

First part of the UNION selects 2nd `max(date)` if there's data for today's date. Second part of the union selects `max(date)` if there's no data for Today.

Comment: Does that take into account that *I always need to select the yesterdays date*?

Comment: It takes into account that you need to select the second largest date. My question to you is: do you need to select both the data for yesterday's date *as well as* the data for the second max date? Your question was not very clear and hence my answer only addresses the issue of selecting the data with the second largest date.

Comment: @ icarus i want the next max date if there is date entered today, if there is no date entered as today then i want yesterdays date

Comment: i guess we need to use if

Comment: if the max date i = todays date then i want the next max date otherwise i want the max date

Comment: @ GSerg i always need the date for yesterday or the next max date for example saturday and sunday is not working day so i need the date on 02/13/2020 as my max date instead of todays date